# How to define a command using \lowercase in \csname

Tags: tex-core

I was being lazy and had a lot of commands of the form

```
\def\foo{...Foo...}
```

So I was thinking about taking an approach like

```
\def\bar#1{\expandafter\gdef\expandafter\csname\lowercase{#1}\endcsname{...#1...}
```

or something along the lines of

```
\def\bar#1{\edef\tmp{\lowercase #1}\expandafter\gdef\expandafter\csname\tmp\endcsname{...#1...}}
```

wanting to use it like `\bar{Foo}}` and followed by `\foo`,
but this obviously won't work because `\lowercase` can't be expanded further. How do I do this properly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
\def\bar#1{\lowercase{\expandafter\gdef\csname#1\endcsname}{...#1...}
```

does something perhaps related to what you want.

Comment: It works, thank you. It feels sufficiently magic enough, that I wouldn't have come up with it myself.